# CSquotes + biblatex: best practice when having references in footnotes

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, csquotes, quotation

In my text, I create my bibliography with biblatex and generate the quotation marks with csquotes. I want to have my references in the footnotes. Unfortunately, I am a little lost when it comes to the best method of setting the references consistently. I have created an MWE in which I create three examples of direct quotations (A-1 to A-3) and two examples of paraphrasing (B-1 and B-2).

Perhaps someone can tell me from their own experience what the most practical solution would be. In any case, the lower case letters and missing full stops are still a problem... Thank you so much!!

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[german=swiss]{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\footnote{#1}}

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=ascii, style=authortitle-dw, 
uniquename=false, idemtracker=false, idembib=false]{biblatex} 

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

    @book{book123,
        title = {Book},
        author = {Author, Peter},
        date = {2005},
        }

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}
    Es sagte, dass \foreignblockquote{english}[{\cite[10]{book123}}]{I am a 
    quote}, was sehr kontrovers ist.
     
    A-1) Es sagte, dass \foreignblockquote{english}[{\cite[10]{book123}}]{I am 
    also 
    a quote}, was sehr kontrovers ist.
     
    A-2) Es sagte, dass \foreignblockquote{english}{I am another 
    quote}\footcite[10]{book123}, was sehr kontrovers ist. 
    
    A-3) Es sagte, dass \foreignblockquote{english}{I am another 
        quote}\footnote{\cite[10]{book123}}, was ziemlich kontrovers ist.
    
    B-1) Es sagte, dass es noch ein weiteres Zitat sei.\footcite[10]{book123}
    
    B-2) Es sagte, dass es NOCH ein weiteres Zitat 
    sei.\footnote{\cite[10]{book123}}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not actually an answer to your question but the `archaeologie` package is perfecct for your style of footnote citations.

Comment: It seems to me you are looking for `\footcite`, which would take care of capitalization and punctuation for you (automatically and consistently). The `csquotes` manual recommends for citation in footnotes: `\SetCiteCommand{\footcite} \renewcommand{\mkccitation}[1]{#1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\foreignblockquote` only has a simple `<cite>` argument that is passed on to `\mkcitation`. With the settings of the question that means that your citations are essentially

```
\footnote{\cite{foo}}
```

But normally it is more convenient to work with `\footcite` (or even better `\autocite`), which gives slightly different output as it capitalises the first word and finishes the footnote contents off with a full stop. You can get a more similar result if you replace `\footnote` by `\mkbibfootnote`, which includes the code for capitalisation and the full stop.

You can do even better and use `\foreignblockcquote` instead of `\foreignblockquote`. The `csquotes` commands with a `c` in their name have a complete citation interface to work with `biblatex`, which means that you can use them more or less as if they were a `\...cite` command when it comes to the citation. You don't have to worry about hiding additional square brackets in curly braces etc.

In your case I'd suggest

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=swiss]{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\mkbibfootnote{#1}}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle-dw, 
uniquename=false, idemtracker=false, idembib=false,
autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Es sagte, dass \foreignblockcquote{english}[10]{sigfridsson}{I am a 
  quote}, was sehr kontrovers ist.
     
  A-1) Es sagte, dass \foreignblockcquote{english}[10]{sigfridsson}{I am 
  also a quote}, was sehr kontrovers ist.

  A-1) Es sagte, dass \foreignblockquote{english}[{\cite[10]{sigfridsson}}]{I am 
  also a quote}, was sehr kontrovers ist.
     
  A-2) Es sagte, dass \foreignblockquote{english}{I am another 
  quote}\autocite[10]{sigfridsson}, was sehr kontrovers ist. 
    
  B-1) Es sagte, dass es noch ein weiteres Zitat sei.\autocite[10]{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ebd., S. 10.]

Comment: Thanks!! I'll use \autocite and \foreignblockcquote, it works perfectly and looks neat.